# How to solve recurrence relations using generating functions that do not start at $a_0$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

For example,
$$
a_{n+1} - 2a_n = 2, \\ \textrm{for } n \geq 1, a_1 = 1
$$
I tried using
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n+1}x^{n+1} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2a_n x^{n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2x^{n+1}
$$
if we let $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$
$$
f(x) - a_1 x - 2x f(x) = \frac{2x^2}{1-x}
$$
and I get 
$$
f(x) = \frac{x^2 + x}{(1-x)(1-2x)} = \frac{A}{1-x} + \frac{B}{1-2x}
$$
but the partial fraction decomposition is not giving me a solution. Also, using method of undetermined coefficients I got the right answer which is
$$
a_n = 2^{n-1}3 - 2
$$

edit1: typos

Comment: The problem might fit into the usual framework of generating functions better if you define $a_0 = -1/2$.  That way your recursion is satisfied for $n \ge 0$ and you have $a_1=1$ as a consequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should the fraction on the RHS be

$$ \frac{2x^2}{1-x}\text{?}$$

edit: You should end up with

$$f(x) = \frac{2x^2}{(1-2x)(1-x)} + \frac{x}{(1-2x)}$$

which you can simplify and do partial fractions with and get the desired answer.

Comment: $n$ starts at $1$ so it should start at $x$. Could you elaborate?

Comment: $n$ starts at 1, but the first term is $2x^2$.
Also, you missed a coefficient 2 infront of the second summation. 
That will help you get the right answer.

Comment: Thanks, I edited mistakes. But I am still getting wrong answer. When I solve using partial decomposition get $A=-1$ and $B=1$.

Comment: Remember the degree of the numerator should be less than the numerator when you convert to partial fractions. Here we have, 
$\frac{x^2+x}{(1-x)(1-2x)} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{5x-1}{(1-2x)(1-x)}= \frac{1}{2}+\frac{3/2}{1-2x}-\frac{2}{1-x}$

Comment: Do you mind showing whole process for the partial fraction decomposition? I did not know about that rule.

Comment: @PhoxKiD It's polynomial division. $\frac{x^2+x}{2x^2-3x+1} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2x^2+2x}{2x^2-3x+1} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{(2x^2-3x+1)+(5x-1)}{2x^2-3x+1}. $

Comment: @PhoxKiD It's clear why this "rule" is true. The highest degree term you can get from partial fractions is less than the degree of the denominator. 
For example we can't write $\frac{x^2}{(1-x)(1+x)}$ as $\frac{A}{1-x}+\frac{B}{1+x}$ because there will be no degree 2 term in the numerator.